# Is this function continuous at (0,0)

Tags: continuity

I am trying to solve whether $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{(x^2+y)}$ is continuous at$(0,0)$ or not where $f(0,0)$ is defined to be $0$. I converted this to polar by substituting $x=r\cos p,  y=r\sin p$ where $r$ tends to $0$ and got the result it is continuous. Book says it is not continuous. Where am I wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: How did you get the result it is continuous? You ask people to show where you are wrong without showing your work.

Comment: A good first start for these sorts of problems is to approach $(0,0)$ along a ray, say $t \mapsto (t, \alpha t)$. This will produce the limit $\alpha$ which clearly depends on how you approach $(0,0)$.

Comment: You can use the polar method to show that it is NOT continuous. You CANNOT use the polar method to show it is continuous.

Answer (score 6):

Let $x=t$ and $y=-t^2+h(t)$, where $h(t) \to 0$ as $t\to 0$, define a parametric curve.  Then, we see that on this curve

$$\begin{align}
f(x,y)&=\frac{xy}{x^2+y}\\\\
&=\frac{t(-t^2+h(t))}{t^2+(-t^2+h(t))}\\\\
&=\frac{t}{h(t)}(h(t)-t^2)\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now, if $h(t)=t^4$, for example, then we see that along this parametric curve

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)&=\lim_{t\to 0}f(t,-t^2+t^4)\\\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0^{\pm}}\left(t-t^{-1}\right)\\\\
&=\mp \infty
\end{align}$$

and therefore, the function $f(x,y)$ cannot be continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Very nice answer. +1

Comment: @donantonio Thank you. Much appreciative!  But there is an easier way to show failure of existence.