Differentiability of a function and existence of directional derivatives
I have a problem. In the book of Classical Elemental Analysis of Hoffman - Marsden assure that the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2+y}$ if $x^2 \neq -y$ and $f(x,y) = 0$ if $x^2 = -y$ is not differentiable because the function $f$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$ but I think it is not true because it is continuous since f(0,0) = 0 and with polar coordinates: $x = r\cos{\theta}, y = r\sin{\theta}$ when $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ then $r \rightarrow 0^{+}$, therefore
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,y) &= \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^2+y}\\
 &= \lim_{r\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{(r\cos{\theta})(r\sin{\theta})}{r^2\cos^2{\theta}+r\sin{\theta}} \\
&= \lim_{r \rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{r\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}}{r\cos^2{\theta}+\sin{\theta}} \\
&= 0
\end{aligned}
then we have to $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,y) = f(0,0)$. The book uses that example to show that although all directional derivatives of $f$ exist at $(0,0)$, the function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ and use the continuity argument of $f$ in $(0,0)$ but I think it is incorrect. I sense that the function is not differentiable at (0,0) but not with the argument given in the book, I have tried multiple options but I have not been able to. Any suggestions?

See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1418864/42969, or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1876278/42969

You are treating $\theta$ as constant, but it is not necessarily constant.

$\frac{xy}{x^2+y}\leqslant \frac{xy}{y}=x$, considering positive cases.

Despite the polar-coordinates limit, the two-variable limit does not exist. To see why, let $c$ be a constant and consider the curve $x=\frac{ct}{t-c}$, $y=\frac{ct^2}{t-c}$, which passes through the origin at $t=0$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
    \lim_{t\to 0} f(x(t),y(t)) &= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\frac{ct}{t-c} \cdot \frac{ct^2}{t-c}}{\left(\frac{ct}{t-c}\right)^2 + \frac{ct^2}{t-c}}
\\&= \lim_{t\to0}\frac{c^2t^3}{(ct)^2 + ct^2(t-c)}
\\&= \lim_{t\to0}\frac{c^2t^3}{ct^3} = \lim_{t\to 0} c = c
\end{aligned}$$

(Open in Geogebra)

You might wonder how I arrived at that parametrization. Using Geogebra to plot the surface $z=f(x,y)$, I guessed a parametrization of the level curve $f(x,y) =c$ satisfying $y=tx$. Solving $f(x,tx)=c$ for $x$ gives $x=\frac{ct}{t-c}$.

Your function is not continuous at $(0,0)$. Just approach the origin along one of the branches of the hyperbola $x^2+y=xy$ (the one containing the origin). Along such branch, your function is identically equal to one, so the limit is $=1$.
